# Regex to find alphanumeric match with day part of datetime

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, .net-2.0

I have to match string like `"DAY1","DAY2","DAY3"....."DAY31"` with regex in vb.net. I tried something like this - `^?DAY(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$` but it did not work. Please help.

The pattern should have succesfull match if the source string is either `DAY1` or `DAY2` or `DAY3` to `DAY31` like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex (removed the `?` and the `0` before the first number):

```
^DAY([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. You guys are like Regex gurus. Awesome.